# Designing wordpress themes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I was just wondering, must your website's css be the same as wordpress css in terms of class names and id's before you can modify your website to a wordpress site? Like what I mean is, I give my div for the post area a different class intead of wordpress's class i.e post  and the same for the post title, date etc. If yes, how can this be achieved? I've head about child themes but not sure if I'm on the right track. Any suggestion people

Comment: This really belongs on the Wordpress Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't has its own css classes. You can make own classes . 
You can start here: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkkooyPMB3I` and go with next parts.